# В activity приложения не срабатывает метод onPause при вызове другого полноэкранного activity

Tags: android, activity

У нас есть Android приложение, работающее на движке marmalade и мы столкнулись с проблемой, что при отображении полноэкранной видеорекламы от Chartboost в активити нашего приложения не отрабатывает метод onPause(), т.е. запускается реклама в полноэкранном режиме, а наше приложение продолжает работать (играет музыка, анимация) и идёт наложение звуков.
Все остальные рекламные sdk (Supersonic, InMobi) у нас интегрированы аналогичным образом и отрабатывают корректно (при отображении видеорекламы приложение приостанавливается).
Активити от chartboost по гайду в манифесте прописано следующим образом:

```
    <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
           android:excludeFromRecents="true"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Вопрос в том, как так может быть, что вызываемое полноэкранное активити не приостанавливает вызывающее активити и есть ли способ как-то обойти данную проблему?

Comment: Могу предположить, что это из за `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`. Попробуйте поставить `false`.